# How to perform a $text search on a 'joined' collection via $lookup?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

i’m new at Mongo, using v3.2. I have 2 collections Parent & Child. I’d like to use Parent.aggregate and use $lookup to “join” Child then perform $text $search on a field in Child and a date-range seach on the parent. Is this possible...?

Comment: Operations like `$text` or `$near` variants **require** that an index be used, and therefore can only be applied in the "very first" aggregation pipeline stage. Therefore since you need `$lookup` to "join" first, then such a query operation cannot be applied. MongoDB "still" does not really do joins. You would be better off querying the "child" directly with a `$text` query and then running a seperate query for the associated "parents".

Comment: Should `$lookup` be altered to allow a "query" to filter the collection to "lookup" from then this would be "theoretically" possible since the "source collection" would come from the result of it's own "query" output. However this is not presently the case. Somewhat related to [SERVER-21612](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-21612) at least in the effect this would have on the "query" issued in the `$lookup` expression.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @BlakesSeven. I really like the referenced idea of including a query to the `$lookup` stage! In the meantime, I'll re-architect my collections to circumvent the need to have a parent/child relationship between collections in order to accommodate `$text` searching the index.

Comment: Looks like you don't need to as an answer with a working solution is already posted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In line with the comments already given, it is true that you cannot perform a [`$text`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) search on the results of a [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)since there would not be an available index at any stage other than the very first pipeline stage. And it is true that especially considering that you really want the "join" to occur based on the results from the "child" collection, then it would indeed be better to search on the "child" instead.

Which brings the obvious conclusion that in order to do this you perform the aggregation on the "child" collection with the initial [`$text`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) query and then [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) the "parent" instead of the other way around.

As a working example, and just using the core driver for demonstration purposes:

```js
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/rlookup',function(err,db) {
  if (err) throw err;

  var Parent = db.collection('parents');
  var Child = db.collection('children');

  async.series(
    [
      // Cleanup
      function(callback) {
        async.each([Parent,Child],function(coll,callback) {
          coll.deleteMany({},callback);
        },callback);
      },
      // Create Index
      function(callback) {
        Child.createIndex({ "text": "text" },callback);
      },
      // Create Documents
      function(callback) {
        async.parallel(
          [
            function(callback) {
              Parent.insertMany(
                [
                  { "_id": 1, "name": "Parent 1" },
                  { "_id": 2, "name": "Parent 2" },
                  { "_id": 3, "name": "Parent 3" }
                ],
                callback
              );
            },
            function(callback) {
              Child.insertMany(
                [
                  {
                    "_id": 1,
                    "parent": 1,
                    "text": "The little dog laughed to see such fun"
                  },
                  {
                    "_id": 2,
                    "parent": 1,
                    "text": "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"
                  },
                  {
                    "_id": 3,
                    "parent": 1,
                    "text": "The dish ran away with the spoon"
                  },
                  {
                    "_id": 4,
                    "parent": 2,
                    "text": "Miss muffet on here tuffet"
                  },
                  {
                    "_id": 5,
                    "parent": 3,
                    "text": "Lady is a fox"
                  },
                  {
                    "_id": 6,
                    "parent": 3,
                    "text": "Every dog has it's day"
                  }
                ],
                callback
              )
            }
          ],
          callback
        );
      },
      // Aggregate with $text and $lookup
      function(callback) {
        Child.aggregate(
          [
            { "$match": {
              "$text": { "$search": "fox dog" }
            }},
            { "$project": {
              "parent": 1,
              "text": 1,
              "score": { "$meta": "textScore" }
            }},
            { "$sort": { "score": { "$meta": "textScore" } } },
            { "$lookup": {
              "from": "parents",
              "localField": "parent",
              "foreignField": "_id",
              "as": "parent"
            }},
            { "$unwind": "$parent" },
            { "$group": {
              "_id": "$parent._id",
              "name": { "$first": "$parent.name" },
              "children": {
                "$push": {
                  "_id": "$_id",
                  "text": "$text",
                  "score": "$score"
                }
              },
              "score": { "$sum": "$score" }
            }},
            { "$sort": { "score": -1 } }
          ],
          function(err,result) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result,undefined,2));
            callback(err);
          }
        )
      }
    ],
    function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      db.close();
    }
  );

});
```

This results in the [`$text`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) matches from the query on the `Child` populated within each `Parent`, as well as being ordered by `"score"`:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "Parent 1",
    "children": [
      {
        "_id": 2,
        "text": "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog",
        "score": 1.1666666666666667
      },
      {
        "_id": 1,
        "text": "The little dog laughed to see such fun",
        "score": 0.6
      }
    ],
    "score": 1.7666666666666666
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "name": "Parent 3",
    "children": [
      {
        "_id": 5,
        "text": "Lady is a fox",
        "score": 0.75
      },
      {
        "_id": 6,
        "text": "Every dog has it's day",
        "score": 0.6666666666666666
      }
    ],
    "score": 1.4166666666666665
  }
]
```

This ultimately makes sense and will be a lot more efficient than querying from the "parent" to find all "children" in a [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) and then "post filtering" with `$match` to remove any "children" that did not meet criteria, and then subsequently discarding the "parents" without any match.

The same case is true for mongoose style "referencing" where you included an "array" of "children" within the "parent" instead of recording on the child. So as long as the `"localField"` on the child ( `_id` in that case ) is the same type as defined within the array on the parent as `"foriegnField"` ( which is will be if it was working with `.populate()` anyway ) then you are still getting the matched "parent(s)" for each "child" in the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) result.

This all comes down to reversing your thinking and realizing that the `$text` results are the most important thing, and therefore "that" is the collection on which the operation needs to be initiated.

It's possible, but just do it the other way around.

---

### Using mongoose style with list of referenced children in the parent

Just showing the reverse case for references on the parent as well as date filtering:

```js
var async = require('async'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/rlookup');

var parentSchema = new Schema({
  "_id": Number,
  "name": String,
  "date": Date,
  "children": [{ "type": Number, "ref": "Child" }]
});

var childSchema = new Schema({
  "_id": Number,
  "text": { "type": String, "index": "text" }
},{ "autoIndex": false });

var Parent = mongoose.model("Parent",parentSchema),
    Child = mongoose.model("Child",childSchema);

async.series(
  [
    function(callback) {
      async.each([Parent,Child],function(model,callback) {
        model.remove({},callback);
      },callback);
    },
    function(callback) {
      Child.ensureIndexes({ "background": false },callback);
    },
    function(callback) {
      async.parallel(
        [
          function(callback) {
            Parent.create([
              {
                "_id": 1,
                "name": "Parent 1",
                "date": new Date("2016-02-01"),
                "children": [1,2]
              },
              {
                "_id": 2,
                "name": "Parent 2",
                "date": new Date("2016-02-02"),
                "children": [3,4]
              },
              {
                "_id": 3,
                "name": "Parent 3",
                "date": new Date("2016-02-03"),
                "children": [5,6]
              },
              {
                "_id": 4,
                "name": "Parent 4",
                "date": new Date("2016-01-15"),
                "children": [1,2,6]
              }
            ],callback)
          },
          function(callback) {
            Child.create([
              {
                "_id": 1,
                "text": "The little dog laughed to see such fun"
              },
              {
                "_id": 2,
                "text": "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"
              },
              {
                "_id": 3,
                "text": "The dish ran awy with the spoon"
              },
              {
                "_id": 4,
                "text": "Miss muffet on her tuffet"
              },
              {
                "_id": 5,
                "text": "Lady is a fox"
              },
              {
                "_id": 6,
                "text": "Every dog has it's day"
              }
            ],callback);
          }
        ],
        callback
      );
    },
    function(callback) {
      Child.aggregate(
        [
          { "$match": {
            "$text": { "$search": "fox dog" }
          }},
          { "$project": {
            "text": 1,
            "score": { "$meta": "textScore" }
          }},
          { "$sort": { "score": { "$meta": "textScore" } } },
          { "$lookup": {
            "from": "parents",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "children",
            "as": "parent"
          }},
          { "$project": {
            "text": 1,
            "score": 1,
            "parent": {
              "$filter": {
                "input": "$parent",
                "as": "parent",
                "cond": {
                  "$and": [
                    { "$gte": [ "$$parent.date", new Date("2016-02-01") ] },
                    { "$lt": [ "$$parent.date", new Date("2016-03-01") ] }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }},
          { "$unwind": "$parent" },
          { "$group": {
            "_id": "$parent._id",
            "name": { "$first": "$parent.name" },
            "date": { "$first": "$parent.date" },
            "children": {
              "$push": {
                "_id": "$_id",
                "text": "$text",
                "score": "$score"
              }
            },
            "score": { "$sum": "$score" }
          }},
          { "$sort": { "score": -1 } }
        ],
        function(err,result) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(result,undefined,2));
          callback(err);
        }
      )
    }
  ],
  function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }
);
```

With the output:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "Parent 1",
    "date": "2016-02-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "children": [
      {
        "_id": 2,
        "text": "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog",
        "score": 1.1666666666666667
      },
      {
        "_id": 1,
        "text": "The little dog laughed to see such fun",
        "score": 0.6
      }
    ],
    "score": 1.7666666666666666
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "name": "Parent 3",
    "date": "2016-02-03T00:00:00.000Z",
    "children": [
      {
        "_id": 5,
        "text": "Lady is a fox",
        "score": 0.75
      },
      {
        "_id": 6,
        "text": "Every dog has it's day",
        "score": 0.6666666666666666
      }
    ],
    "score": 1.4166666666666665
  }
]
```

Noting that the `"Parent 4"` which would otherwise of had the largest ranking is removed since the date does not fall in the query range applied with [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/).

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth example and code! The issue i've run into with this is now that getting the count. When querying the Children $text search first, then at another stage, querying the Parent and performing a $group to show unique Parents, the count is relative to the Children results and not the parents grouping aggregation. Am I articulating that clearly?

Comment: @CoryRobinson You could probably make that clearer by [asking another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) as that would be the best way to express what you need. This was about showing you that the approach requires doing the `$text` search "first" and then joining to the other collection.